# Devolver imagen en un json

Tags: java, rest

Tengo la sgte clase, la imagen se guarda en la bbdd en la variable foto:

```
public class Personas{
  private String name;
  private Date date;
  private Blob foto;
```

MI pregunta es si creo un servicio rest y si esto me devolvera la foto para poder despues representarla en mi parte web

Comment: puedes convertir la imagen a una cadena string de 64bits y enviarla como texto y luego la vuelves a convertir a imagen en tu destino.

Comment: es lo que estaba pensando, pero si devuelvo 10 000 registros no se lo lento que pueda llegar ser

Comment: sera lento igualmente.... 10.000 registros sean imagenes o cadenas de textos o pepinos, depende de su tamaño total. Tendras un extra añadido en la conversión a base64 pero creo que será despreciable y el cuello de botella será en la comunicación